# php in html - display table

Tags: php, html, arrays, mongodb-query

I have simple DB query that that will output group country codes and the count of instances in the DB. I'm trying to display this data in a table with PHP.

When viewing the page nothing displays past the `<tbody>` tag. I've searched for how to properly run PHP inline with HTML and I don't see what im getting wrong. suggestions?

```
<table id="countryList" class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th width="50%" class="tableheading">Country</th>
             <th width="50%" class="tableheading" style="text-align:center;">Count</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php
      for($x = 0; $x < count($cn_count['result']); $x++){
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td class='tablebody' title='Unkown'>".$cn_count['result'][$x]['_id']['cn']."</td>";
          echo "<td class='tablebody' style='text-align:center;'>".$cn_count['result'][$x]['count']."</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
          if($x == 14){
          break;
          }
        }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

the mongoDB query

```
$cn_count = $collection->aggregate([['$group' => ['_id' => ['cn' => '$cn'],'count'=>['$sum'=>1]]],['$sort' => ['count' => -1]]]);
```

The query returns the expected results, it simply appears that the inline PHP is not running after the `<tbody>` tag. otherwise the page would still display the rest of the content.

----VarDump----

```
    php > var_dump($cn_count);
object(MongoDB\Driver\Cursor)#11 (2) {
  ["cursor"]=>
  array(17) {
    ["stamp"]=>
    int(0)
    ["is_command"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["sent"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["done"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["end_of_event"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["in_exhaust"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["has_fields"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["query"]=>
    object(stdClass)#13 (0) {
    }
    ["fields"]=>
    object(stdClass)#10 (0) {
    }
    ["read_preference"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["mode"]=>
      int(1)
      ["tags"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["flags"]=>
    int(0)
    ["skip"]=>
    int(0)
    ["limit"]=>
    int(0)
    ["count"]=>
    int(2)
    ["batch_size"]=>
    int(0)
    ["ns"]=>
    string(9) "spam.mail"
    ["current_doc"]=>
    object(stdClass)#15 (2) {
      ["_id"]=>
      object(stdClass)#14 (1) {
        ["cn"]=>
        string(2) "NA"
      }
      ["count"]=>
      int(264)
    }
  }
  ["server_id"]=>
  int(1)
}
php >
```

Comment: can you show the code of the database query & $cn_count variable assignation

Comment: var_dump'ed $cn_count['result']?

Comment: Also add:  ini_set('display_errors','on'); at the top of your file and post the output, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not get anything inside `tbody`, it is safe to say your problem is in this line:

```
for($x = 0; $x < count($cn_count['result']); $x++){
```

Since `$x` is properly initialized, you have a problem with `$cn_count`. It is either:

- not initialized
- not a proper parameter for `count`
- empty

Comment: Why is he getting a down vote. It seems like one of those suggestion is the cause. Did you print_r the $cn_count['result'] to see what kind of results you get?

Comment: the issue was that $cn_count was not initialized. $cn_count was the query cursor and I did not use the Iterator rewind.